# Alignment in CSS

Tags: html, css

2 lines are displayed in the UI lyk . It's there in a single span element

```
       I am testing this, and it looks good
however I am skeptic about it.
```

I want to align both the lines such that it looks like.

```
I am testing this, and it looks good
however I am skeptic about it.
```

both the lines start together unlike in the previous case.

How this can be achieved using CSS.

Comment: Could you please show your CSS stylesheet? I've got a feeling that your span:first-line has padding applied to it.

Comment: Adding margin or padding to inline elements will just affect the beginning and end of the span (see http://jsfiddle.net/hA33h/1/). CSS-Tricks has a good article about workarounds here: http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say something without codes but I guess, you are looking for text-indent. I'm assuming your lines are in the same container and not separate lines, just a part of the same paragraph.

[CSS text-indent property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp)

Make sure that css codes affecting your text doesn't have text-indent property or set text-indent to 0px.

Answer (score -5):

If it doesn`t work with "text-indent: 0;", than the solution is with JS/jQuery

Eg - remove extra white spaces using jQuery:

```
$('.pln').html($('.pln').html().replace('  ', '');
```